# go to page option feature missing PrimeNG paginator

Tags: angular, pagination, primeng, primeng-turbotable

I am using PrimeNG with Angular 6, I have used Turbo-table with pagination, but go to specific page directly not one by one feature is missing in Pagination. Did any one implemented out here?

https://stackblitz.com/edit/turbo-table-row-exp-issue-zt49t1

Sorry, I could have done this before, Implemented sample

I want a go to specific page option in paginator. like
[image]

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please add some code of your efforts according to [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Thanks!

Comment: https://stackblitz.com/edit/turbo-table-row-exp-issue-zt49t1

Sorry , I could have done this before, Implemented sample

I want a go to specific page option in paginator.

Comment: Thanks, please edit your question to include the essential code directly (not as link).